# I am finding it hard to understand inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

Am wondering of this case: Employee inherits from Person and Manager inherits from Employee, which statement will be correct?

```
Person alice = new Employee();
Employee bob = new Person();
Manager cindy = new Employee();
Manager dan = (Manager)(new Employee());
```

Comment: What happens when you *try*?  Does this code compile?  Do the objects work the way you expect them to?

Comment: read tutorials. there are many articles explaining every case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code can be simply run from VS.

Comment: This looks like a test question and it shouldn't be answered.. well, until exam time is expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's draw a sketch:

```
  Person
    Employee  (Employee can be though as a subset of Person)
      Manager (Manager can be though as a subset of Employee)
```

so *every* `Manager` is `Employee`, *every* `Employee` is `Person`. The sequence is *transitive*, and thus *every* `Manager` is `Person`. Now, let's see

```
  Person alice = new Employee();
```

You've created an `Employee` instance (`new Employee();`) and then try to assign it to `Person` (`Person alice =`) instance; since *every* `Employee` is `Person` you can do it.

On the contrary:

```
  Manager cindy = new Employee();
```

You've created an `Employee` instance and then try to assign it to `Manager` instance. You can't do it since there's no such a rule that *every* `Employee` is `Manager` (Quite the *opposite*: every `Manager` is `Employee`, but not *vice versa*).

Answer (score 0):

Only the first one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

One of the uses of inheritance is the ability to cast an inherited type as a base type (not the other way around.)

So you could do

```
Manager danTheManager = new Manager();
Employee danTheEmployee = (Employee)danTheManager;
Person danThePerson = (Person)danTheManager;
Person alsoDanThePerson = (Person)danTheEmployee;
```

The point is that you should always be able to cast an inherited type as one of its base types and use it as an instance of that type. (Ideally try to avoid doing it the other way - inspecting an object to see what inherited type it is.)

It's called the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html) (L in [SOLID](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp).) The simple explanation is that you should always be able to cast a `Manager` as an `Employee` or `Person` and use it as an instance of that type because it inherits from them. You don't want to have to check to see what type an object is because if it's a `Manager` it works one way but if it's an `Employee` it works a different way.